# OneToOneField getting "Cannot resolve keyword"

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have seen this question been asked many times but couldn't adapt the solutions to my situation.

I have generated my models from a legacy database in MySQL using python manage.py inspectdb and changed the Pointsofinterestcoordinateslist model's primary key to an OneToOneField but can't get a query to work.

models.py

```
class Parentregionlist(models.Model):
    regionid = models.IntegerField(db_column='RegionID', primary_key=True)   
    parentregionid = models.IntegerField(db_column='ParentRegionID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ...
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'parentregionlist'

class Pointsofinterestcoordinateslist(models.Model):
    regionid = models.OneToOneField(Parentregionlist, primary_key=True, db_column='RegionID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    regionname = models.CharField(db_column='RegionName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    regionnamelong = models.CharField(db_column='RegionNameLong', primary_key=True, max_length=191)  # Field name made lowercase.
    latitude = models.DecimalField(db_column='Latitude', max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    longitude = models.DecimalField(db_column='Longitude', max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    subclassification = models.CharField(db_column='SubClassification', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='TimeStamp')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pointsofinterestcoordinateslist'
```

views.py

```
def city(request, name):

attractions = Pointsofinterestcoordinateslist.objects.filter(parentregionlist__parentregionid=2114)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

Cannot resolve keyword 'parentregionlist' into field. Choices are: latitude, longitude, regionid, regionid_id, regionname, regionnamelong, subclassification, timestamp

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/london

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('otezo',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\projects\otezo\otezo\views.py" in city
  21.     attractions = Pointsofinterestcoordinateslist.objects.get(parentregionlist__parentregionid=2114)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  325.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  679.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  697.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1301.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1328.                     current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector, allow_joins=allow_joins)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1144.         lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1030.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in names_to_path
  1386.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /london
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'parentregionlist' into field. Choices are: latitude, longitude, regionid, regionid_id, regionname, regionnamelong, subclassification, timestamp
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field that goes from Pointsofinterestcoordinateslist to Parentregionlist (*please* give these models better names) is `regionid`, not `parentregionlist`.

```
attractions = Pointsofinterestcoordinateslist.objects.filter(regionid__parentregionid=2114)
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of model names, that actually say what the model is doing, but this is really not helpful. At least make them camel-case.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks, what I'm trying to do is filter Pointsofinterestcoordinateslist from a field in its parent model. I thought that setting the primary key as OneToOneField to the parent model would allow me to filter it.

Comment: You guys have made a good point. I've been lazy after getting the models generated from legacy database. :) Gonna make them came-case. Thanks

Comment: Hey Daniel, got it, prety simple, thank you! Thought the relationship should be made by the model name not by the field name.